# Determine what fields to save in Windows Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to store an entity called Tshirt into a Windows Azure table storage along with a Blob on Windows Azure Blob storage.
That entity Tshirt contains a field called Image (byte[]) but I don't want to save that in my table.
How can I indicate in my class that I don't want to save that field?

```
public class Tshirt : TableServiceEntity
{

    public Tshirt(string partitionKey, string rowKey, string name)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = rowKey;
        this.Name = name;

        this.ImageName = new Guid();
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }


    private string _color { get; set; }

    public string Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set { _color = value; }
    }


    private int _amount { get; set; }

    public int Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value; }
    }


    [NonSerialized]
    private byte[] _image;


    public byte[] Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; }
    }


    private Guid _imageName;

    public Guid ImageName
    {
        get { return _imageName; }
        set { _imageName = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: pls, help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156980/save-to-windows-azure-table

Comment: For version 2.0 of the SDK, here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15179860/828957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to expose the field as a pair of methods rather than an actual property:

```
public byte[] GetImage()
{
    return _image;
}

public void SetImage(byte[] image)
{
    _image = image;
}
```

If that's not an option, then you can remove the Image property when you're storing the entity by handling the WritingEntity event.  ([Credit to Neil Mackenzie](http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/entities-in-azure-tables/))

```
public void AddTshirt(Tshirt tshirt)
{
    var context = new TableServiceContext(_baseAddress, _credentials);
    context.WritingEntity += new EventHandler<ReadingWritingEntityEventArgs>(RemoveImage);
    context.AddObject("Tshirt", tshirt);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

private void RemoveImage(object sender, ReadingWritingEntityEventArgs args)
{
    XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
    XElement imageElement = args.Data.Descendants(d + "Image").First();
    imageElement.Remove();
}
```