# Error when try to save in Windows Azure Table

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-storage

I did a method which add a user in storage. Below is the code and the error that I'm getting.

```
   public string addusr(string nome, string cidade, string cpf, string email, string telefone)
    {
        try
        {
            if (nome.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo nome.";

            if (cidade.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo cidade.";

            if (cpf.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo cpf.";

            if (!Valida(cpf))
                return "f:CPF Invalido.";

            if (email.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo email.";

            Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$");
            if (!rg.IsMatch(email))
            {
                return "f:Email Invalido";
            }

            List<UserEntity> lst = new List<UserEntity>();
            var _account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
            var _context = new CRUDUserEntities(_account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), _account.Credentials);
            if (_context.Select(cpf).Count() > 0)
                return "dup";

            var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
            var context = new CRUDUserEntities(account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), account.Credentials);
            UserClientEntity entity = new UserClientEntity() { nome = nome, cidade = cidade, cpf = cpf, email = email, telefone = telefone };
            context.ADDUSociate(entity);
            return "k";
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            string error =  "f:" + exc.Message + "|" + exc.StackTrace;
           // Trace.WriteLine("Erro no login: " + error , "Information");
            return error;
        }
    }
```

**When I try to add a user...I'm getting this error:**

```
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      f:An error occurred while processing this request.| at            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
         at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
        at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CommonUtils.      <LazyEnumerateSegmented>d__0`1.MoveNext()
        at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
        at mobile.Service1.addusr(String nome, String cidade, String cpf, String email, String telefone)
    </string>
```

I don't know what is wrong..

Comment: Does it work on the emulator?

Comment: I dont have ran in the simulator...here the simulator does not work. I'm getting this error when I try to simulate "The system is missing prerequisite to execute the service see the output window for more information ".

Comment: I suggest you start with getting the emulator working for azure storage and debug this in visual studio.

Comment: It would be useful to know the type of error as well as the error message, so you might want to improve your try...catch block.  Are you setting the partition key and row key, I can't see that in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats causing the error but you do miss a `context.SaveChanges();` after

```
context.ADDUSociate(entity);
```

"I suggest you start with getting the emulator working for azure storage and debug this in visual studio." 
I think you dont have the correct Azure sdk installed. Try to reinstall it and the emulator should work. You can follow this guide: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/