# Exclude property from being persisted in Azure Table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

This is not duplicate of earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489232/prevent-azure-tableentity-property-from-being-serialized-in-mvc-4-webapi/21071796#21071796) as this is applicable only for older version of Table SDK. With Azure.Data.Tables, this solution does not work

I have a property in my entity that derives from ITableEntity which I do not want to persist as it is stored in the blob (due to storage size limitation)

I tried JsonIgnore, XmlIgnore but nothing works. I could not find any updated documentation from MS on same. Even creating custom serializer does not work.

Entity class:

```
public class AzTableEntity : ITableEntity
{
    public AzTableEntity()
    {

    }

    public AzTableEntity(int length, byte[] bytes, string fileName)
    {
        RawBytes = bytes;
        Length = length;
        FileName = fileName;
    }
    // Attribute to ignore as it would be stored in Blob 
    public byte[] RawBytes { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the SDK you're using?

Comment: I am using Azure.Data.Tables v12.2.0

Comment: I have closed this question as duplicate. Please let me know if the solution does not work for you and I will reopen the question. HTH.

Comment: Using [IgnoreDataMember] attribute worked. Thanks